# How to update the state when deleting an item using React-Redux and Rails api?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, reactjs, redux

I am trying to create a delete functionality in my application which seems to be deleting the object from the backend just fine, but not in the frontend.

Here is how I structured my project:

*in actions/deleteJournal.js*

```
export const deleteJournal = (journal) => {
    return dispatch => {
        fetch(`http://localhost:3001/journals/${journal.id}` , {
            method: "DELETE" })
            .then(resp => resp.json())
            .then(journal => { dispatch({ type: "DELETE_JOURNAL", journal })
        })
    }
}
```

*in reducers/journalsReducer.js*

```
const initialState = {
    journals: [],
    loading: true
}
const journalsReducer = (state=initialState, action) => {

    switch(action.type) {
        case "LOADING":
            return {
                ...state,
                loading: true
            }
        case "SET_JOURNALS":
            return {
                ...state,
                loading: false,
                journals: action.journals
            }
        case "ADD_JOURNAL":
            return {
                ...state,
                journals: [...state.journals, action.journal],
            }
        case 'DELETE_JOURNAL':
            return { 
                journals: state.journals.filter(todo => todo.id !== action.id),
                ...state    
                
            }
            

        default: 
        return state;
    }

}

export default journalsReducer
```

*in components/List.js*

```
import React, { Component } from 'react'
import { connect } from 'react-redux'
import Journal from './Journal'
import { deleteJournal } from '../actions/getJournals'

class ListFiltered extends Component {

    
    render() {
        const journals = this.props.journals.map( journal => journal.locationId === this.props.locationId && <Journal key={journal.id} title={journal.title} content={journal.content} id={journal.id} deleteJournal={this.props.deleteJournal} />)

        return (
            <div>
                {journals}
                <p></p>
            </div>
        )
    }
}

const mapStateToProps = state => {
    return {
        journals: state.journals
    }

}

export default connect(mapStateToProps, {deleteJournal})(ListFiltered)
```

*in components/Journal.js*

```
class Journal extends Component {
    
    render() {
        const { id, title, content } = this.props;
      

        return (
            
            <div>
                <ul>

                    <li>
                        <h3>{ title } </h3>
                        
                        <p> { content }</p>   <button onClick={() => this.props.deleteJournal(this.props) }>Delete</button>
                        
                      


                    </li>
                </ul>
                
            </div>
        )
    }
}

export default Journal
```

So this seems to be giving me an error **" Uncaught (in promise) SyntaxError: Unexpected end of JSON input
at deleteJournal.js:48"**
I checked my server and it seems to be deleting it from there but nothing in the frontend and when I refresh the item is deleted.

What can I do so it automatically deletes the item from the frontend?

Answer (score 0):

I suspect the issue may be with your line

```
.then(resp => resp.json())
```

What is the body of the response when you issue the `DELETE` request? If it's not a valid JSON object, then JavaScript would throw the error you're seeing.

As you're not using the parsed JSON at all, you could conceivably remove that line:

```js
export const deleteJournal = (journal) => {
    return dispatch => {
        fetch(`http://localhost:3001/journals/${journal.id}` , {
            method: "DELETE" })
            .then(journal => { dispatch({ type: "DELETE_JOURNAL", journal })
        })
    }
}
```

...but you might want to have some of checking that the DELETE method was executed successfully.

How you do that's up to you and your Rails API, but I'd typically expect to see the response have an HTTP status in the `2xx` range when something is successfully deleted, and in the `4xx` range if something couldn't be deleted (e.g., if the ID wasn't recognised, or there were dependency issues which meant the deletion request was rejected). That feels outside the scope of this question though.

Comment: hey I got rid of that line and that seemed to not show that error any more but it still won't delete the item from the frontend, the backend seems to work just fine. It is getting to that particular ID, but I still need to refresh for that particular item to not show up. I think the issue is in the list.js or the journal.js

Comment: Oh, there's another error. You're dispatching an action with `type` and `journal` keys, but your reducer is using `action.id` in the filter. That should probably be `action.journal.id` (or just send the ID in the dispatch payload).

Comment: Hey so I figured it out, the line .then(resp => resp.json()) was important. It was just that I wasn't rendering json in the destroy function in the journal controller (backend), adding that fixed the issue. Sometimes it really is the simplest things, huh.